# Javascript style.opacity removes a 0 from the string I'm giving

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'n my app the user is able to change the colour of the background but not the pattern, you can adjust the background behind the pattern and the patterns opacity. I ask the user for a percentage which is actually a number between 0 and 100. Then it goes through this function.

try to go from 1 to 10 then from  10 to 20 you can see that the first 10 times it skips 0.1 at first but later it goes from 0.01 each step.

```js
function changeOpacity(){
 var patternOverlay = parseInt(document.getElementById("opacityBox").value);
 if(patternOverlay != 100){
  document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = "0." + patternOverlay;
 }
 else if(patternOverlay < 10){
  document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = "0."+ "0" + patternOveylay.toString();
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = 1;
 }
}
```

```css
#bg{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50px;
  }
p{
  float: left;
  }
#patternOverlay{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://www.drave.nl/kaartenmaker/includes/images/pattern0.png');
  }
```

```html
<input id="opacityBox" min="0" max="100" oninput="changeOpacity()" type="number"></input><p>Put a number for opacity here</p>
<div id="bg"> <p> </p> </div>
<div id="patternOverlay"><p></p></div>
```

As you can see the number comes from opacityBox input, then I filter it so 100 turns into `opacity:1;`

then if they put in a value like 5 it should be going to css like `opacity: 0.05;` but CSS in the browser it displays as `opacity: 0.5;`

Comment: A value of 9 would go into the `patternOverlay != 100` control and skip the `patternOverlay < 10` control.  Have you considered nesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is way easier and simpler to do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = (1/100)* patternOverlay;
```

```js
function changeOpacity(){
 var patternOverlay = parseInt(document.getElementById("opacityBox").value);
 document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = (1/100)* patternOverlay;
}
```

```css
#bg{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50px;
  }
p{
  float: left;
  }
#patternOverlay{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://www.drave.nl/kaartenmaker/includes/images/pattern0.png');
  }
```

```html
<input id="opacityBox" min="0" max="100" oninput="changeOpacity()" type="number"></input><p>Put a number for opacity here</p>
<div id="bg"> <p> </p> </div>
<div id="patternOverlay"><p></p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic is wrong

```
if(patternOverlay != 100){ // -infinity THROUGH 99 and 101 to +infinity meet this condition!!!
    document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = "0." + patternOverlay;
} else if(patternOverlay < 10){ ...
```

Basically all numbers are going into the first if! It will not go into the second if, since the first one already met the condition. The second else if should be first.

Logic should be something like

```
if(patternOverlay>=0 && patternOverlay<10) {
} else if (patternOverlay<100) {     
} else { 
}
```

Comment: My `patternOverlay` is `-1`.

Comment: So you get put into the else for not following directions. ;P

Comment: I would prefer to use `val = Math.max(0, Math.min(val, 100))` though :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `step` argument

```
<input step="0.05" min="0" max="1" oninput="changeOpacity()" type="number">
```

And then use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`

**Example**

```js
function change(e) {
  document.getElementById("target").style.opacity = parseFloat(e.value);
}
```

```html
<input step="0.05" min="0" max="1" value="1" oninput="change(this)" type="number">
<div id="target">Change my opacity</div>
```

Or, if you really want it to be percentage 1-100...

**Example 2:**

```js
function change(e) {
  document.getElementById("target").style.opacity = parseInt(e.value)/100;
}
```

```html
<input step="5" min="0" max="100" value="100" oninput="change(this)" type="number">
<div id="target">Change my opacity</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you had a typo. It should be overlay, not oveYlay. Second, the logic should be switched around so that it checks to see if there is a number < 10 first.

```
function changeOpacity(){
    var patternOverlay = parseInt(document.getElementById("opacityBox").value);
    if(patternOverlay < 10){
        document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = "0."+ "0" + patternOverlay;
    }
    else if(patternOverlay != 100){
        document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = "0." + patternOverlay;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("patternOverlay").style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution

http://jsfiddle.net/gp7ub4Lf/1/

var p = 5;

```
if(p >= 10){
        alert("0." + p);
    }
    else if(p < 10){
        alert("0."+ "0" + p);
    }
    else{
        alert(1);
    }
```

Comment: Why did you add `else`?

Comment: How would you get an alert for value 1 if there is no else..? Does browser automatically throw an alert..? It is just a demo to show how the if conditions work. Not an answer.

Comment: But if `p=1` then it will alert `0.01`. Seems to me like you don't understand the concept of if-statements.